# why system(cmd) function need to set the command string with the & background parameter in Linux-arm

Tags: c, linux

I'm going to run a regular program on a Linux-arm embedded device.

I tried to use `system(cmd)` function to run linux shell `cmd` in my program.

`cmd` would be a audio playing command `"aplay -N sound.wav"`

If `cmd` is as above, there will be no sound come out of my linux device, and the process of the program will in the `T` state (traced or stopped).

If cmd is set as `"aplay -N sound.wav &"`, things will work just fine.

My question is what caused that, why does the `"&"` background parameter matter in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: **Speculation:** When you don't send your aplay with '&' to the background, the system function blocks until aplay ends. Maybe this is not allowed on your embedded device and your process is killed because of it?

Comment: On a side note, you should use QProcess::startDetached for daemon process starts in a Qt project rather than the low-level call... http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qprocess.html#startDetached More importantly, can you provide a short snippet which reproduces the issue? For me, it works just fine here.

Comment: @henryyao: Does it work on your desktop Linux or it is the same? Have you tried different format as well, just in case?

Comment: @LaszloPapp It does work on my Laptop, however, if i switch it to the embedded device, i will need the "&" parameter.

Comment: @Greenflow I undertand system() is a blocking function. However, I dont think it is not allowed in my embedded device, what's more, my process is not killed, its being traced or stopped.

Comment: @henryyao: does it work without -N?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes, it does work without -N

Comment: @henryyao: good, is that an acceptable solution for you, or you would like to desperately get it work with -N? If yes, I will wrap these comments up in a reply...

Comment: @LaszloPapp Sorry. There is a misunderstaind here. It does work without -N, but not without &.

Comment: Right... what is the difference between your desktop and embedded? What are the aplay versions, disbtributions, etc? Frankly, I am havind troubles to figure this out. Everything works fine here as expected... Also, why do you use this in a Qt application at all rather than using QtMultimedia to play it for you?

Comment: @LaszloPapp My aplay: version 1.0.24.2 by Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>. It does work on the laptop or desktop, but not on the embedded device, I've tested it on more than two laptops and two embeddeds.  For the QtMultimedia thing, I'm not fimiliar with that and I think it needs format converting since I'm using a .wav file.

Comment: You could play wav files with QtMultimedia. I think it is time to refactor your design. You are not using Qt in a Qt software. :-)

Comment: emmm, you have the point. But I'm still curious about the '&' thing.

Comment: Have you tried exec and similar flavors instead of system(cmd)?

Comment: Also, I retagged your question as it has nothing to do with, but plain C. Hope, you do not mind. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If aplay allows for STDIN to act as a controller, running it forground may not provide the control input it expects. The backgrounding may detach STDIN and have aplay revert to default "play once until finished" mode. Do you have a man page for aplay?

Comment: I do not understand this reply. He is not using STDIN, but a file supplied.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got why.
I'm running my qt program in the '&' mode, so I guess in any system(cmd), that cmd must contains a '&'.

I tried to run my qt program without the '&', after that, the cmd without '&' would be working fine.

So I guess the cause is you cannot run fork a foreground child process from a background father process.

Comment: I think it is a misconception. You claimed it would be working on your Linux desktop with the same scenario, so if it was like this which I am not sure, it would not explain why it is working on desktop ... This is all false of course if you had told us it works on Linux desktop, but would have tried without '&' in there for the parent Qt process...

Comment: Apologize for that. I did not notice the & thing in my laptop since it was directly run from qtcreator, without a command line.

Comment: @LaszloPapp The exec() will replace my current process, which means when the exec() is executed, the current process will be terminated, this is not what I want. That's why I'm using system() function to fork() another process.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I will take a loot at that. Thanks a lot for the replys